# Impose on vs. impose upon

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

As both **impose on** and **impose upon** are of correct prepositions, what is their difference, let's say you are writing an academic essay.

> - I think **impose on** sounds academic already, *BUT,*
> - does **impose upon** more academic sounding?

Ex.1 Artists should have no limitations **imposed on** them.

Ex.2 Artists should have no limitations **imposed upon** them.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

As noted  by McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.

[impose (up)on someone:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/impose+on)

> to force something on someone. ***(Upon is formal and less commonly used than on.)***
>
> - Don't try to impose your ideas upon me! The colonists tried to impose their values on the indigenous peoples.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impose%20on%2Cimpose%20upon&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimpose%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpose%20upon%3B%2Cc0) shows that the preposition “upon” has been less commonly used in the last decades.

Comment: So "impose on" is not formal? Only impose upon?

Comment: @JohnArvin - yes, it is more colloquial, but it can be used in formal contexts too.

Comment: @JohnArvin In this *specific* case, yes. It's a matter of formality. However, this answer is incomplete. In some cases, the two prepositions serve distinctly different purposes. For instance, you *put on clothes* but you never *put upon clothes*.

Comment: @JasonBassford - the question is about impose on vs impose upon, and it is not incomplete. Put on/upon clothes is a different story and not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @user070221 A complete answer would give definitions of the two prepositions and put them into a broader context. This is only a basic answer. It doesn't go into explanations. I'm not saying it's wrong—but it could easily be expanded.

Comment: @JasonBassford - it is not basic, it answer the question in full. If you feel like providing more information, post your own answer.

Comment: The difference between them is still vague to me. While **impose on** them is "informal", and **impose upon** is formal, the frequency of usage is the opposite. Oh man, as I see it, both prepositions are becoming "obsolete" when you want to use them in an academic essay.